# Radix Sort, the value of r

Tags: java, data-structures, bit-manipulation, radix-sort

Please refer to the following code for radix sort:

```
class RadixSort
{
    public static void radix_sort_uint(int[] a, int bits)
    {

        int[] b = new int[a.length];
        int[] b_orig = b;


        int rshift = 0;
        for (int mask = ~(-1 << bits); mask != 0; mask <<= bits, rshift += bits) {

            int[] cntarray = new int[1 << bits];

            for (int p = 0; p < a.length; ++p) {
                int key = (a[p] & mask) >> rshift;
                ++cntarray[key];
            }


        for (int i = 1; i < cntarray.length; ++i)
                        cntarray[i] += cntarray[i-1];


            for (int p = a.length-1; p >= 0; --p) {
                int key = (a[p] & mask) >> rshift;
                --cntarray[key];
                b[cntarray[key]] = a[p];
            }


            int[] temp = b; b = a; a = temp;
        }


        if (a == b_orig)
            System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, a.length);
    }
}
```

This is downloaded from wikipedia.

I feel that the algorithm will work only for value of `bits` parameter that divide 32 perfectly. Thus, `bits` should be something like 2 or 4 , but not 10. Please let me know if I am right.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No

Long answer:

The probable line of confusion is:

```
for (int mask = ~(-1 << bits); mask != 0; mask <<= bits, rshift += bits) {
```

`mask <<= bits` shifts the bits of `mask` left by `bits`, padding the right with zeros. If `bits` doesn't divide 32, then the full 32 bits won't be utilised. So while `bits` *should* divide 32, choosing a value that doesn't does not break the code.